# ArcGIS, Combine tool. Crashes once reaching 40% progress

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, combine

I'm trying to combine 7 rasters containing soil related data. Rasters are 4.5G, give or take. All the rasters contain integer values. Once the combine tool reaches 40% progress, it stalls and arcmap shuts down itself.

Any suggestions on what is wrong and how to solve it?

This is my code:

```
series_raster  = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
texture_raster = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
wam_raster     = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
slope_raster   = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)
ecodist_raster = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4)
ecoreg_raster  = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(5)
vegtype_raster = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(6)
Output_raster  = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(7)

rasters = []
rasters.append(series_raster  )
rasters.append(texture_raster )
rasters.append(wam_raster     )
rasters.append(slope_raster   )
rasters.append(ecodist_raster )
rasters.append(ecoreg_raster  )
rasters.append(vegtype_raster )

arcpy.AddMessage('> Combining rasters...')
outCombine = Combine(rasters)

# Save the output 
arcpy.AddMessage('> Saving combined raster...')
outCombine.save(Output_raster)
```

Comment: Are you able to combine those rasters manually?

Comment: I tryied, but takes forever and stalls at some point of the process. What I'm trying now is to break up the raster in smaller pieces. Maybe it's a matter of memory. I'll keep this entry posted.

Comment: so I've splited the raster in smaller pieces, seemed to work ok at the begining. But then I've got the error: "Too many unique values".   :[
Suggestions anyone?

Comment: Reclassify them. Period. I don't  believe 1 and 2 degrees slope are much different for this type of analysis

Comment: I did two things that worked:  I've splitted the rasters in smaller parts, and I setted up 50k total unique combinations allowable. Wosking smoothly now. Thanks!